# Filtering values in a Data Frame using several values from one column

Tags: python, pandas

For the following data frame I want to filter data based on count value. I want to keep count 10, 5, and 2:

```
index      count
    1           10
    2           5
    3           2
    4           1
    5           6
    6           7
    7           "tab"
```

I know that I can write the code as

```
df[(df.count==10) | (df.count==5) | (df.count==2) |  (df.count=="tab")]
```

Is there any simpler way to do it? I have more than 20 values. I tried the following, but it did not work:

```
df[(df.count==[10, 5, 2, "tab"])
```

Thank you.

Comment: `df.count` will not work, use `df['count']` (`count` is a function, `.count` will access the function, not the column).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `isin`:

```
df[df['count'].isin([10, 5, 2, "tab"])]
```